# Wordpress Permalink with Categories

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Quick question, so i set categories, and also setup custom structure, so url will post as www.myblog.com/category/post-name.

my question is, how do i set it so that if the post is uncategorized or i have a post that I want the permalink to show from the root for a specific article like

www.myblog.com/post-name/

it seems if i set the structure to custom category / post, then I can't have any posts structure coming directly from the root.  I have tried several different ways to accomplish this, but I keep getting 404 errors, as the link structure is not working correctly.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-permalink/

Comment: Do you need the uncategorized posts really to be a post? You could use a site for this approach instead.

Comment: basically I have two types of posts, one that I would like the url structure to come from the root domain and one where I want url structure to include category.  if I set with permalinks for /category/post-name, then all posts look like this:    http://www.myblog.com/category/post-name, when I need some to look like this, http://www.myblog.com/post-name

Answer (score 0):

If you want www.myblog.com/post-name/ this kind of url structure then login to your WP site>Settings>Permalinks>Check Post name>Save Changes.

And if you want www.myblog.com/category/post-name this kind of url structure then login to your WP site>Settings>Permalinks>Optional>enter Category base(if you want to show category in url) or choose Tag base (if you want to show tag in url)

it will show : www.myblog.com/topics/uncategorized/

Comment: yes, i understand that.  the issue is that i want a different url structure for certain posts, as some i want to come from the www.myblog.com/post-name and some to come from the category select www.myblog.com/category/post-name

Comment: permalink structure effects all posts, which is the issue I am having, thanks for your response, I don't think you understand my issue.